# RegExp: Last occurence of pattern that occurs before another pattern

Tags: regex, git-bash

I want to take a text pattern that occurs the last before another text pattern.

For example I have this text:

```
code 4ab6-7b5
Another lorem ipsum
Random commentary.

code f6ee-304
Lorem ipsum text 
Dummy text

code: ebf6-649
Other random text
id-x: 7662dd41-29b5-9646-a4bc-1f6e16e8095e

code: abcd-ebf
Random text
id-x: 7662dd41-29b5-9646-a4bc-1f6e16e8095e
```

I want to take the last `code` that occurs before the first occurrence of `id-x` (which means I want to get code `ebf6-649`)

How can I do that with regexp?

Comment: I'm using git bash, so I think it's the unix engine

Comment: By "with regexp", I take it you mean "with git-bash"? (I mean, why do you care if the answer happens to use a regex?)

Comment: @JasonSwartz I actually think the previous version of this question was perfectly fine and would have given you more useful answers. Solutions to this limited form are likely to create false positives in your actual input.

Comment: What chars can the `Other random text` line have?

Comment: [`git-grep`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-grep.html)?

Comment: @acdcjunior any character

Comment: @Cyborgx37 using git-grep would be great to achieve this, actually I want it in git, but do you have any idea on how could be this achieved using git-grep?

Comment: @ruakh I want to get `ebf6-649` from a text buffer using a unix command, so I thought I could use regexp

Comment: I dont know git-bash, so here's a suggestion that may work (I dont know how to apply it to git0bash, though): `code:\s(\S+-\S+)\r?\n.*\r?\nid-x:` the first group would be the number you need...

Comment: @JasonSwartz - sorry... was actually asking if that's what you are using. `git-bash` is just the shell... or perhaps you don't know how to run a regex in git-bash?

Comment: I don't know how to run a regex in git-bash and I also don't know the regex to give me the text I need.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your regex flavor supports [lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), you can use a solution like this

```
^code:[ ]([0-9a-f-]+)(?:(?!^code:[ ])[\s\S])*id-x
```

And you can find your result in capture number `1`.

How does it work?

```
^code:[ ]           # match "code: " at the beginning of a line, the square 
                    # brackets are just to aid readability. I recommend always
                    # using them for literal spaces.

(                   # capturing group 1, your key
  [0-9a-f-]+        # match one or more hex-digits or hyphens
)                   # end of group 1

(?:                 # start a non-capturing group; each "instance" of this group
                    # will match a single arbitrary character that does not start
                    # a new "code: " (hence this cannot go beyond the current
                    # block)

  (?!               # negative lookahead; this does not consume any characters,
                    # but causes the pattern to fail, if its subpattern could
                    # match here

    ^code:[ ]       # match the beginning of a new block (i.e. "code: " at the
                    # beginning of another line

  )                 # end of negative lookahead, if we've reached the beginning
                    # of a new block, this will cause the non-capturing group to
                    # fail. otherwise just ignore this.

  [\s\S]            # match one arbitrary character
)*                  # end of non-capturing group, repeat 0 or more times
id-x                # match "id-x" literally
```

The `(?:(?!stopword)[\s\S])*` pattern let's you match as much as possible without going beyond another occurrence of `stopword`.

Note that you might have to use some form of multi-line mode for `^` to match at the beginning of a line. The `^` is important to avoid false negatives, if your `random text` contains `open:`.

[Working demo](http://rubular.com/r/naopKQFNyy) (using Ruby's regex flavor, as I'm not sure which one you are ultimately going to use)